# mysql random field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database with about 800 columns at the moment and add to it every so often.

**How do I add a new field with a random string of 4 letters and numbers eg : 4h3k**

I do not want duplicates to happen either.

Thanks chaps!

EDIT

OH MA GAD NO I MEAN ROWS NOT COLUMNS.

800 ROWS!

Comment: **Eight hundred columns**.  800.  800?  ... *How?*  I want to see some of the names you've already come up with.  This oughta be *gold*.

Comment: create rand str, check if it allready exists (if y, update, if not, make new one=

Comment: Wow... I'm really curious what reason you'd have for 800 columns - I can't believe it's all normalized...

Comment: If that's normalized I'm going to eat a hat.  I mean, he's trying to create a new column with *junk* appended to the end, there's no way at all that there's any concept of normalization in that database.

Comment: @Charles - The names must be like this: `customer1`, `customer2`, `customer3`...

Comment: I want to think OP meant **rows**

Comment: You should consider normalising your database: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: I was so amazed with 800 columns that I've even forgotten to downvote question and vote for close for not being constructive. BTW, @user1616846, why are you trying to do that?

Comment: @Charles A downvote means "question shows no research effort" - apparently the OP has not researched proper database design enough; and there oughtta be a close reason for "wrong question". ;)

Comment: @Charles Maybe I am missing something but I can't figure out where exact problem is. Does OP has problems with generating random strings? Or connecting with database? Or adding new field to existing table?

Comment: What do you mean by "*random*"?  For what purpose are these strings to be used?

Answer (score 4):

As the comments already show. Why in the world would you want 800 columns? Seems like a mayor flaw in your database structure. Perhaps you can explain what you want to store so we can help you to setup a proper structure. 800 (random!) columns can never be what you want.

If you do plan to keep this structure, you could use `SHOW COLUMNS FROM mydb.mytable WHERE FIELD='newcolname'` to see if it already exists.

But I highly recomment to reconsider your database model. How are you even selecting things from it since its random columns? You always use select * and then loop trough all cols?

Answer (score 0):

this maybe can help you .

```
// first  u generate string with numbers and letters with length 4 
function genRandomString() {
$length = 4;
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$string = '';    

for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
    $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
}

 return $string;
 }
  echo genRandomString();        // will echo one radom string like  4h8l
 // second check if the random string exist in table then use new generated string
 $new_random_string = genRandomString() ;
 $strings = mysql_query("SELECT `string` FROM `table`");
 while ($string = mysql_fetch_row($strings)) {

 if ($new_random_string == $string[0]) 

   echo genRandomString() ;

 }

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`string`) VALUES ('".$new_random_string."')");
```

Comment: This does not actually answer the question.  This inserts random strings.  The question is about giving new table columns unique names by using random strings.

Comment: @charles if its like that  it will be , `CREATE` column with this generated string and he will check if this column exist then generate new column as i showed him . and i dont see any reason for your downvote , i give him all what he can do and checks if exist then do new column.